# Fitting matrices inside a fraction!

Tags: matrices, fractions

here is a what I want to do in latex, tried using matrix b-matrix and arrays but keep getting errors about bad environment and missing $.

[image: matrix in a fraction]

Help much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please edit your question and put in the code there. The "other" space is reserved for *answers*. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need the math delimiters (here `\[` and `\]`) outside `\frac{}{}`; the following compiled fine for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{
    C=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        C_{11} & C_{12} & \dotso & C_{1n} \\
        C_{21} & C_{22} & \dotso & C_{2n} \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        C_{m1} & C_{m2} & \dotso & C_{mn} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    }{s}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You're missing the backslash in front of `vdots`, i.e. `\vdots`